# Move button after adding subview

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, view, viewcontroller

Edited following comments below - using constraints to control the layout.

I am trying to add/remove views controllers, which are set up within the storyboard, via a button. The button and any previously added views should move down the screen as per the following visual format strings:

Optional("V:|-50-[viewXIB0(100)]-30-[buttonKey]")

Optional("V:|-50-[viewXIB1(100)]-30-[viewXIB0(100)]-30-[buttonKey]")

Optional("V:|-50-[viewXIB2(100)]-30-[viewXIB1(100)]-30-[viewXIB0(100)]-30-[buttonKey]")

(This is the println output of the visual format string fed into NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat.)

Thanks already to the comments below, the view does appear each time the button is pressed, and moves down the page correctly. However, the spacing between the superview and top view is zero - without margin. A similar issue also when additional views are added - each one gets tucked underneath the spacing. The bottom spacing is greater than the desired 30. And, after a few inserts, even weirder things start to happen towards the top of the screen.

[image: iPhone6 with messed up autolayout]

There are no constraint errors on build or running. When my computer is running super slow, I do see it appear briefly in the correct place, and then snap to the top of the screen. I think I can hear it laughing at me too, but that might be a joke. Autolayout is enabled in both View Controllers.

The full method I'm using to add the view from a touch up inside button is:

```
@IBAction func addVCBenj(sender: AnyObject)
{
    // remove original constraint from button
    if (topConstraintBenjV != nil)
    {
        view.removeConstraint(topConstraintBenjV)
        topConstraintBenjV = nil
        println("addVCBen constraints removed")
    }
    // remove previous constraints as views are added
    if (constraintV != nil)
    {
        view.removeConstraints(constraintV!)
        println("removed")
    }

    // instantiate add add the view within the storyboard VC
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let myVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("VCtoInsert") as UIViewController
    view.addSubview(myVC.view)

    // create and add a unique key for each view in the dictionary of views
    viewsDictionaryKey = "\(viewsDictionaryString)\(viewsDictionaryCounter)"
    viewsDictionaryCounter += 1
    viewsDictionary[viewsDictionaryKey!] = myVC.view

    // create the visual format string for layout
    suffixVisualFormatString_V = "[" + viewsDictionaryKey! + "(100)]-30-" + suffixVisualFormatString_V
    visualFormatString_V = prefixVisualFormatString_V + suffixVisualFormatString_V
    println(visualFormatString_V)

    // create and add horizontal and vertical constraints
    let constraintH = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[\(viewsDictionaryKey!)(>=300)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: metricsDictionary, views: viewsDictionary)

    myVC.view.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    constraintV = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(visualFormatString_V!, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: metricsDictionary, views: viewsDictionary)
    self.view.addConstraints(constraintV!)
    self.view.addConstraints(constraintH)
}
```

I've seen the WWDC videos, and searched for a similar problem, but in truth, I'm now so confused, I don't know what to even search for anymore.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `child.myButton.frame` and not the actual whole view itself (vc.view), as that would move everything down. If you want to use Autolayout you could setup a IBOutlet for the top constraint like you would a view and just change it's .constant (may need to call view.layoutifneed).

Comment: You can try to move your button in the method :
    `-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews`
of your view controller

Comment: To move your UIButton having AutoLayout enabled, you have to adjust the constraints of the button. One way would be via IBOutlets as @BooRanger suggested. [A similar (possible duplicate) question is posted here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13744932/animating-moving-views-under-usage-of-autolayout), with a difference that Objective-C is used there.

Comment: @BooRanger, I am using a button to add VCs, keeping the button below the last VC is the challenge.

Comment: You do not have to create the button programmatically to access the constraints. Just create an `IBOutlet` for the respective constraint  and manipulate it. Have a look at the answer by RJR in the question I linked above. This should really help you.

Comment: @Nero - yes indeed. It helped a lot. Things are moving, but not as I expect. I've updated the question after fighting with this for a few days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per a comment by BooRanger, by adding an IBOutlet to the top and bottom contraints, it was possible to manipulate the views each time a button was pressed. Ultimately, however, collection views are an easier way to add and remove views.

Comment: Comments are liable to be deleted at any time - for posterity, could you edit your answer to include the relevant parts of information which you found helpful? Many thanks.