# move UILabel and UIImageVIew on UITableviewcell with autoLayout

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, autolayout

I've a tableview of folders and when the user tap on a folder It will show up the subfolder, with the name moved of 20 pixel to get a "child graphical effect". Now, switching to `Autolayout`, I can't move programmatically the `UIView`'s element with the code:

```
- (void) configureView {

    if (self.cellMode != NVCellModeSelect) {
        [self setBackgroundColor:[NVGlobals homeCellBackgroundColor]];
        //Indenting label
        CGRect r = self.titleLabel.frame;
        r.origin.x = kLabelsInitialX + self.item.level*10;
        self.titleLabel.frame = r;

        //Indenting folder
        r = self.thumbnail.frame;
        r.origin.x = kFolderInitialX + self.item.level*10;
        self.thumbnail.frame = r;

        //Indent triangle
        r = self.triangleIcon.frame;
        r.origin.x = kTriangleInitialX + self.item.level*10;
        self.triangleIcon.frame = r;
    }
}
```

But now It doesn't seems to work. How to move elements programmatically in a `UITableViewCell` with autoLayot?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Animating/Moving views under usage of Autolayout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13744932/animating-moving-views-under-usage-of-autolayout)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

1. You'll need to keep a reference to the leading constraints of each subview and adjust their `constant` values when your cell is in the indented state.  Remember to set them back to the default value if the cell is reused or becomes unindented.
2. Use `tableView:indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath:` to do most of the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: Both are good suggestions, but #2 is the proper way to do it.

Comment: I've read that  tableView:indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath: doens't work in iOS8 with custom UiTableCell. Is It right?