# Strange UIView cutting while using transform

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a freeformed xib loaded into scroll view. Xib consists of two `UIImages`.

Then I try to scale down the xib view and set its `center`:

```
self.xibView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.2, 0.2);
[self.xibView setCenter:CGPointMake(self.scrollViewContent.center.x, self.scrollViewContent.center.y)];
```

It works fine and I get predictable result: http://monosnap.com/image/d09XHn7dJ8uJTABxTiv0HqzwmhrdED.png (grey color shows scroll view area)

Debugger output:

```
xib frame: {{450, 120}, {60, 60}}
scrollview content frame: {{0, 0}, {960, 300}}
scrollview content offset: {320, 0}
scrollview content inset: {0, 0, 0, 0}
scrollview content center: {480, 150}
xib center: {480, 150}
```

But if I try to move my xib somewhere but the content center (I changed `y` coordinate by 1 point)... :

```
self.xibView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.2, 0.2);
[self.xibView setCenter:CGPointMake(self.scrollViewContent.center.x, self.scrollViewContent.center.y + 1)];
```

... then my xib gets strangely cut: http://monosnap.com/image/GhB1DyfRsAkiRXKXeZ68benqfHfliI.png

Debugger output almost the same:

```
xib frame: {{450, 121}, {60, 60}}
scrollview content frame: {{0, 0}, {960, 300}}
scrollview content offset: {320, 0}
scrollview content inset: {0, 0, 0, 0}
scrollview content center: {480, 150}
xib center: {480, 151}
```

Pay attention that xib's size remained to be the same.

Also I tested this behavior on different transform scale value. So, if to set value to 1, everything works fine. If set it to 0.9, xib gets slightly cut. And the more you scale the xib down the more it cuts the xib.

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to use constraints instead of former `frame` and `central` properties. How to set constraints programmatically perfectly described here: http://www.thinkandbuild.it/learn-to-love-auto-layout-programmatically/ How to animate constraints: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19923225/4637398